# Running qt5 program cannot find symbol

Tags: c++, macos, qt5, dylib

I wrote the program with qt5.6 on mac 10.10. But it crashed when I run. Qt application output is:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_png_create_info_struct
   Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
   Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libPng.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
```

But I compiled the latest version of libpng and installed it in the /usr/local/lib with default name `libpng.dylib`. I tried to rename it with `libPng.dylib` but nothing changed of tips. Why didn't it find the symbol? What should I do to solve it?

Comment: A hunch: you are missing the PNG image format plugin. Check out `macdeployqt` tool, which comes with Qt SDK, if this problem happens with deployed app (if it happens in Qt Creator, then this won't help).

Comment: It happens in Qt Creator and builds with debug version... and I try command `macdeployqt` as you say, getting the following messages: `RROR: no file at "/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.dylib"
ERROR: no file at "/usr/lib/libboost_regex.dylib"
ERROR: no file at "/usr/lib/libboost_python3.dylib"
ERROR: no file at "/Library/lib/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Python"`